# What is maximum size of image that can be used on website?

Tags: html, css, image

I.e in pixels, and in mb?

Wondering this for awhile thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The maximum size of a JPEG image is [65535 x 65535 pixels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpeg).

The maximum size of a PNG image is [2^31-1 x 2^31-1 pixels](http://libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.1/png-1.1-pdg.html). You would have great difficulty constructing an image this large due to memory constraints on typical computers.

Some older platforms cannot operate on files that are over two gigabytes in size. Of course, two gigabyte image files would be awkward to work with in most situations, so unless you're doing astronomy with amazing telescopes, I really wouldn't worry about it.

Since most displays are under 1920 x 1200 pixels, it would probably make sense to resize your images down to this size, unless your intention is to allow your clients to make photographic reproductions of your images -- in which case, give your clients as many pixels as you can.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, there is no such limit, but from a practical point of view, use of images larger than `2 MP (1600x1200)` on your website wont make any sense,it wont be it useful/easier for a wide audience. and w.r.t size in MB, if you're seeking practical solution, an image with `<2MB` would likely serve you in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually the host computer will run out of memory and can't load the image - but I think it is safe to say that you'll never make that happen.

Images for webpages can be as big as you like. You need to think about the convenience (or lack thereof) of the users loading very big images on connections that are now mobile all the time and unstable to say the least.